# Conditional v-bind:check in vuejs

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js

I would like to have my checkbox checked according to existence of particular data in the database. I am using vuejs in laravel. 
Following is my code for checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="{{$complaint->complaintID}}" :checked="CheckCECDecisionSigned({{$complaint->complaintID}})" disabled>
```

And below is my vuejs method:

```
methods: {
        CheckCECDecisionSigned: function (complaintID) {
            if (complaintID) {
                var self = this;
                this.$http.get('/cimsm/public/api/fetchCECDecisionSignature/' + complaintID).then(function (response) {
                    if (response.data.length > 0) {
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            }
        },
```

As you can see, if `response.data.length > 0` then i would like to return true and hence have the checkbox checked. But i can't seem to get the method to return Boolean even when `response.data.length` is greater than `0` Can you help me out?.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will work out, as the call is asynchronous. You should try to bind the state of the checkbox to a variable, and `v-model` the checkbox to it, like:

```
<input type="checkbox"
value="{{$complaint->complaintID}}"
:v-model="isChecked" 
disabled>
```

And then, in the callback of the AJAX function:

```
if (response.data.length > 0) {
  self.isChecked = true
}
```

You will need to solve some issues, like finding another way to pass the `complaintID` to the AJAX function (using Components and Props, maybe?). Check this: https://vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#Checkbox